# Parse server (Back4App) cloud function httpRequest returns 'invalid function' error

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server, back4app, parse-android-sdk

I am trying to send FCM notifications directly on the firebase POST url. When i comment out the httpRequest block, the function executes properly.
When i uncomment the block, it starts to give me 'invalid function (141)' error on Android app.

The request works and delivers notification via postman.

Here's my cloud function:

```
const httpResponse = await Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(
      url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'key='+fcm_key
      },
      body:{
        'data':{
          'key1': 'value1',
          'key2' : 'value2',
          'key3': 'value3',
          'key4': 'value4',
          'key5': 'value5',
          'key6': 'value6',
          'key7': oneParseObject.get('someColumnName')
        },
        'registration_ids': new Array(targetFcmToken)
      }
    );
    return 'Done with status code '+httpResponse.status;
```

Comment: Solution: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/back4app/afYs2o4GNRk/UJS7KfWYBQAJ

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces inside function call were missing.
Solution:

```
const httpResponse = await Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': 'key='+fcm_key
  },
  body:{
    'data':{
      'key1': 'value1',
      'key2' : 'value2',
      'key3': 'value3',
      'key4': 'value4',
      'key5': 'value5',
      'key6': 'value6',
      'key7': oneParseObject.get('someColumnName')
    },
    'registration_ids': new Array(targetFcmToken)
  }
});
return 'Done with status code '+httpResponse.status;
```